# Removing files and folders using linux command

Tags: linux, rm

I have a folder in linux which content folders and many files with name format ".git**?".

how to remove theses files and folders using linux command ?

thanks

Comment: Doh, I've missed that you have subfolders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` as follows:

```
find /path/to/folder -name ".git*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```